# CANlyzer asc file to excel conversion

Tags: export-to-csv

I am using CANalyzer Version 7.6.27 and I have been trying to figure out a way to convert the .asc file into CSV. I have gone through the Vector page and they mentioned to use tools option which I cannot find in the software. I tried to do it in BUS MASTER but still, it is not working.

Comment: Can you show us what you've started?

Comment: Use Excel's "Import Data" feature

Answer (score 0):

When I have exported data from CANalyzer to CSV it has been "signals" (decoded from CAN messages). If you just want to convert the CAN trace (raw fields / data bytes) from .asc to .csv format I suggest:

```py
python -m can.logconvert input.asc output.csv
```

See https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripts.html#can-logconvert